# How to make border as big as text in it

Tags: html, css, border

So it looks like this:[image]

this is the example code of a message:

```css
.allMsg {
  width: 100%;
}

.self {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: #28a745;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.friend {
  text-align: left;
}

#chatWith {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class='allMsg'>
  <p class='self chatMsg'>Hello</p>
</div>
```

How can i make the border as big as the text inside ... I thought the padding was going to work but unfortunately it didn't so please help me.

Comment: Could you be more clear on what you mean when you say "border as big as the text inside"? It sounds like you might be referring to the *margin*, and not the actual css border.

Comment: Your image contains more text than the HTML in your snippet. Can you add the rest of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if you wrap your messages inside another element. So let's say all messages have a full-width element, but friends messages will aligned to the left and have a blue background, while yours will aligned to the right and have a green background. If you don't want to change your markup so much, the easiest is to wrap your messages inside a span, than you doesn't need to change anything else in your html.

```css
.allMsg {
  width: 100%;
}

.self span, .friend span {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.self span {
  background-color: #28a745;
}

.friend span {
  background-color: #2845a7;
}

.self {
  text-align: right;
}

.friend {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='allMsg'>
  <p class='chatMsg friend'>
    <span>hello</span>
  </p>
  <p class='chatMsg self'>
    <span>hy</span>
  </p>
  <p class='chatMsg friend'>
    <span>how are you friend?</span>
  </p>
  <p class='chatMsg self'>
    <span>i'm fine thanks</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use flexbox on the container:

```
.allMsg {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Example:

```css
.allMsg {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.self {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: #28a745;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.friend {
  text-align: left;
}

#chatWith {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class='allMsg'>
  <p class='self chatMsg'>Hello</p>
  <p class='self chatMsg'>This is a test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: so it works but i can't align .friend class to the left of the screen... Do you know why ? It's at the right just like the .self class

Comment: I see you have a CSS class named friend, but what elements does it apply to and how should it look? You don't explain that in your question.

Comment: well it should have blue background color and be aligned left while the .self class should be aligned right. And it applies to the <p> tag with message inside. It's just from another user. and should hould have the same border as you wrote me for the first class like the same style... Ending where the text ends.

Answer (score 0):

Though, this question is quite old, but I'll give my *very simple* solution - I don't know why nobody pointed to this.

Add `width: fit-content` to the elements you want - in this case `.self` and `.friend`

```css
.allMsg {
  width: 100%;
}

.self {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: #28a745;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.friend {
  text-align: left;
}

#chatWith {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

/* just add this portion to your code */
.chatMsg {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class='allMsg'>
  <p class='self chatMsg'>Hello</p>
</div>
```

More about these property values can be found in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285308/how-do-min-content-and-max-content-work)