# How do min-content and max-content work?

Tags: css

How are the `min-content` and `max-content` values calculated in CSS?

And what does intrinsic dimension mean?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Note: "width" in this text refers to the "logical width", not CSS's `width`; that is, the values are also valid for CSS's `height`, if the language direction is vertical (like east-asian languages) or in flexbox or grid. `min-content` and `max-content` are valid values for `width`, `height`, `min-width`, `min-height`, `max-width`, `max-height` and even more properties (like `flex-basis`).

## What are the intrinsic dimensions of a box?

CSS sizing level 3 introduced the concept of *intrinsic* dimensions - the opposite of *extrinsic*. An *extrinsic* dimension of a box is calculated on the box's parent box. For example `width: 80%` is said an *extrinsic dimension* as the `width` of the subject depends on the `width` of its containing box.

Contrarily to that, `width: min-content` is said *intrinsic* as the width of the box is calculated on the dimension of the contents that the box itself contains.

*Intrinsic* dimensions are properties of the box itself, extrinsic dimensions are only available if the box is placed in the document and in a context that permits these values to be calculated. For example, in CSS-flow (the classic CSS layout mode), as you probably know, `height: 20%` has only effect if `height` is defined in the parent element (i.e. it's inheritable); that is a case of an *extrinsic* dimension that is not calculable (when an extrinsic value is not available, CSS fallbacks to its intrinsic equivalent). Instead `height: min-content` is always calculable, as it is *intrinsic* to the box itself, and it is always the same regardless of the box's placement (or the box's absence) in the document.

---

The definition of `min-content` and `max-content` has changed many times over the years but the result always stayed the same, and it is pretty straightforward to grasp. They were originally requested by the community as keywords for `width`, whose computed value would match the widths of a box when the box is `float`ing. And indeed, the definition of these two properties was originally based on the behavior of `float`; now they are more generically defined as follows:

### `min-content`

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#min-content

> The smallest size a box could take that doesn’t lead to overflow that could be avoided by choosing a larger size.

In other words, **the smallest width of a box where the box's contents don't overflow the box itself**.

A good way to visualize this is using, in fact, `float`.

```
/* the computed width of #red in this example 
   equals to specifying #red { width: min-content } */
#blue        { width: 0px; }
#blue > #red { float: left; }
```

[image: min-content]

(GIF source: http://jsfiddle.net/6srop4zu/)

In the above GIF, **the red box's *min-content width* equals the red box's width at the time the blue box's width is 0px** (234px in the GIF, might be different in the jsfiddle).

As you can see, if the red box was made smaller, the word `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious` would overflow the red box, hence in this case the `min-content` equals the width of that particular word, as it is the one that takes the most space horizontally.

### `max-content`

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#max-content

> A box’s “ideal” size in a given axis when given infinite available space. Usually this is the smallest size the box could take in that axis while still fitting around its contents, i.e. minimizing unfilled space while avoiding overflow.

```
/* the computed width of #red in this example
   equals to specifying #red { width: max-content } */

#blue        { width: 99999999999999999px; } /* ~infinite */
#blue > #red { float: left; }
```

[image: max-content]

(GIF source: http://jsfiddle.net/nktsrzvg/)

In the above GIF, **the red box's *max-content width* equals the red box's width when the blue box's width is infinite** (386px in the GIF, might be different in the jsfiddle).

Here, the red box fully takes advantage of the available space on the x axis in the blue box, but without wasting it. The contents are allowed to expand on the relevant axis without restrictions, and the red box wraps them and at the point of maximum expansion.

---

What about `fit-content`, `stretch` and others? These properties are currently being revisited and as such they are not stable (date: July 2018). They will be added here when they get a bit more mature (hopefully soon).

Comment: Very clear explanation. Just one more thing: how do they compare to `auto`? Is there any fundamental difference in design theory between them?

Comment: Auto results in different things depending on the layout used. For example the behavior is different depending on the axis, if you are using block or flexbox or grid, etc.

Comment: @ Wes, But the documentation says `auto` is also intrinsic, only determined by its content?

Comment: width:auto is not always intrinsic. For example it's calculated to the outer box's width (therefore extrinsic) if display:block

Comment: There seems to be one case where `width: min-content` does act according to its specification: when it contains flex items with `flex-shrink: 0`. I documented my findings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65083319/242365).

Answer (score 36):

**min-content:**

The minimum width that a content (a group of words) **needs**. It means width of the biggest word in the content.

Example:

```
hi this is

biggestWordInTheContent

<---- min-content ---->
```

**max-content:**

The maximum possible width that a content (a group of words) can take. It means the width of the content when all the words arranged together in one line.

Example:

```
hi this is a content without considering any line breaks.

<---------------------- max-content ------------------->
```

Comment: This post would be improved by code implementations of your examples rather than just text in code formatting.

Comment: The output on the first one doesn't look like that when using `min-content`, `hi this is` should not break as `biggestWordInTheContent` is longer than the the three words combined. The snippets could have shown this properly as well.

Comment: Nice catch @Yong! I edited the answer. About snippets, I approved it first but I It made the answer more complicated I believe, nothing too complicated to be in snippet, users easily can try it themselves. I want the answer to be minimal and understandable at the first glance!!

Comment: Yes @AhmadMobaraki , I think it was better 'simply' as you described it. It was more direct which is what one needs most of the time

Comment: Good answer, I just don't really understand why this is so. When would you ever want text to never ever wrap no matter how long, or be as big  as the word length? Is this old or new CSS specifications?