# Prevent child from from stretching parent container

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a fixed-position container element with two children. Both children contain text. I want one of the children to dynamically set the width of the container with its content. I want the other child's text to wrap appropriate based on that width.

For example:

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
}

.wrap {
  background: red;
}

.stretch {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    this text is very very long
  </div>
  <div class="stretch">
    shorter text
  <div>
</div>
```

In this example, I would like the container's width to match the shorter green `.stretch` `div`. I want the red `.wrap` `div` to have the same width, with the text wrapped inside, like:

[image: r]

Comment: Just for clarifying, what does this problem have to do with the `fixed position`? or it's only about the parent's width depends on 1 specific child's width?

Comment: I'm not certain how relevant it is. If the position is not fixed, the div always stretches to the full page width, so the wrapping might not occur. In any case, I know the target div is fixed, so I wanted to make sure answers were compatible.

Comment: `width: 0;
    min-width: 100%;` on the red element

Answer (score 2):

The solution's come up with me was:

- The child `div` needs to *stretch its width depends on its content* -> `max-content`
- The parents's width needs to be *as shrink as possible depends on its content* -> `min-content`

The solution code with variant bahaviors:

```css
.container {
  width: min-content;
  
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
}

.wrap {
  background: red;
  width: auto; /* default btw */
}

.stretch {
  background: green;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    this text is very very long
  </div>
  <div class="stretch">
    shorter text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    shorter
  </div>
  <div class="stretch">
    shorter text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="wrap">
    shorter
  </span>
  <div class="stretch">
    shorter text
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can read more about min-content and max-content from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51285309/9787887) or the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2019/WD-css-sizing-3-20190522/#max-content).

> - `max-content` [inline size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-4/#inline-size): the **narrowest** [inline size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-4/#inline-size) it could take *while fitting around its contents* if **none of the soft wrap opportunities within the box were taken**.
> - `min-content` [inline size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-4/#inline-size): the *narrowest* [inline size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-4/#inline-size) a box could take that doesn’t lead to *inline-dimension overflow* that could be avoided by choosing a larger [inline size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-4/#inline-size). Roughly, the inline size that would fit around its contents if **all soft wrap opportunities within the box were taken**.

Comment: Very clever. Good answer

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you! It happens to do what the OP wants but your compliment gives me a guilty feeling that I do not fully understand why it works and what are the other solutions and whether they're better. I'll do some research about this anyway, and update the answer as I can :p.

Comment: width:100% on the wrap is not needed and you can replace width:max-content by `white-space:nowrap`

Comment: for the explanation: min-content force the wrapper to consider the minimum width considering all the possible line break (basically the tallest word on both divs) then max-content will avoid the green one to wrap and will reset the min-content of the parent to its width