# CSS Invalid property value when trying to use the max function alongside min-content

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my `body` element the height of the viewport, but expand if its content exceeds its height. I originally used `min-height: 100vh` to accomplish this.

However, [as stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468131/1541397), an element with a percentage height will not work correctly inside my `body` because it uses `min-height`.

My next idea was to use the [`max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max) function alongside [`min-content`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285308/how-do-min-content-and-max-content-work) on my `body`:

```
body {
  height: max(100vh, min-content);
}
```

However this does not work. In Chrome devtools I get the following warning:

> [image]
>
> Invalid property value

Is there any solution to this problem?

**More details**

- There will be one element inside `body`.
- This element should be able to use percentage-based height values or `auto`.
- The height of the body should expand if the content inside does not fit.
- If the content inside `body` does fit, then any percentage-based height values would be based on the viewport height.

Comment: *an element with a percentage height does not work correctly inside an element that uses min-height.* -->  you need to understand why, because you cannot find a solution to this if you want your element to (1) define the height of the container and (2) has its height as percentage of the container. --> share your full code maybe the solution is somewhere else

Comment: @TemaniAfif Maybe you are misunderstanding my question, I will update the question.

Comment: I understand what you want but you need to share a real use case with code if you want accurate solution. Your body will have 1 element, 2 elements? 1 column, 2 columns? etc ... we should know what you are trying to build. There is no generic solution to what you are asking.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was looking for a generic solution because it could vary. I'll update again. I'm mostly wondering why my solution doesn't work and why it is an invalid property value -- it seems right to me. I'll have to fallback to JavaScript if necessary.

Comment: min-content is not a valid value of max. If you checlk the MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max) you can see the accepted values

Comment: @TemaniAfif That explains it thanks

Comment: It makes me think of something that would work on a CSS grid, but not on a regular height attribute. You could try to set body to `display:flex; flex-direction:column; height:100%;` and add a wrapper div for everything containing `flex-grow:1;` Then I think using 100% inside that div has a different behavior.