# What does `min-height: max-content` mean?

Tags: css, specifications

Why is the height of the parent 200px instead of 300px in the following example?

```css
#p {
    height: 200px;
    min-height: max-content;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#c {
    margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">
      <div id="c">
      </div>
</div>
```

If I set `height: max-content` directly, the height will be set correctly to 300px.  Doesn't this mean `max-content = 300px` in this case?  Therefore shouldn't `min-height: max-content` be the same as `min-height: 300px`?

```css
#p {
    height: max-content;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#c {
    margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">
      <div id="c">
      </div>
</div>
```

And apparently there is no "conflict" between `height` and `min-height`:

```css
#p {
    height: 200px;
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#c {
    margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">
      <div id="c">
      </div>
</div>
```

Moreover, if you change `height` and `min-height` to `width` and `min-width`, it works as expected.  Why?

```css
#p {
    width: 200px;
    min-width: max-content;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#c {
    margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">
      <div id="c">
          hello
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: max-content = max height of what the parent contain... so if the container height will not be respected...

Comment: The intrinsic preferred height. The max-content height is, roughly, the height the content would have if no “soft” line breaks were inserted, i.e., if each paragraph is one long line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do min-content and max-content work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285308/how-do-min-content-and-max-content-work)

Comment: Thanks @MaxiGui, the linked answer explained min-content and max-content, but didn't mention anything about min-height/min-width.  I would like a more explicit answer about min-height.

Comment: @Qian Did you notice my first comment ? if you set as in your 1st example, the height will be taken if the min-height is lower. But if it is the opposite, the min-height will get the priority on the height. in your case you are telling it to adapt the min height depending of the max-height of what it contains...

Comment: @MaxiGui Sorry didn't get your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky and you need to refer to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#sizing-values) to understand this:

> max-content
>
> If specified for the inline axis, use the max-content inline size; **otherwise behaves as the property’s initial value.**

In your case you will fall in to the initial value because the inline size is the width and the block size is the height.

In the [same specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#terms) you can also understand how to identify inline/block size

[image]

In other words, setting `min-height:max-content` will have no effect since it will get computed to the `initial` value but It works for the `min-width` since it's the inline size.

More details: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-4/#abstract-axes

Answer (score -3):

Just remove `height: 200px;`, because it goes into conflict with `min-height`, from the first example and you'll see that your snippet will work well just as the second one.
Like this:

```css
#p {
    min-height: max-content;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#c {
    margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">
      <div id="c">
      </div>
</div>
```

For your main question, `min-height: max-content` mean that the element will keep the minimum height without causing the vertical-overflow of his content.

Comment: Without `height: 200px;` I believe it's the default `height: auto;` setting the height to 300px, not `min-height`.