# CSS - Make list items have a background-color and a width equal to their content

Tags: css, list

```css
li {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

I want to make the list items have both a `background-color` and a width no longer than their content. But if I add the `display: inline-block` property to them, then they all will appear next to each other. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
li {width:max-content;}
```

might be what you look for :

```css
li {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li {
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 90%;/*optionnal but usefull,  avoids them to grow too wide */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>  
  <li>Coffee & Milk & Coffee & Milk & Coffee & Milk & Coffee & Milk & Coffee & Milk & Coffee & Milk &</li>
</ul>
```

see this post to find out more : [How do min-content and max-content work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285308/how-do-min-content-and-max-content-work)

Comment: Tbh, I didn't even know `max-content` exists. Why isn't it shown as a value in the `width` property here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

Comment: @darkchampionz because that site is to *not use*. Check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width

Comment: Hello! The solution seemed to work at first but, as it turned out, it does not wrap the text. Is there any way to fix this too? Thanks

Comment: @darkchampionz did you also set the max-width as in the example ? I added a longer li to show that it wraps ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `span` inside `li` tags

```css
span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Coffee</span></li>
  <li><span>Tea</span></li>
  <li><span>Milk</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to put the list item in a `span`.

```
<ul>
  <li><span>Coffee</span></li>
  <li><span>Tea</span></li>
  <li><span>Milk</span></li>
</ul>

li span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The old float can do it here:

```css
li {
  background-color: yellow;
  float:left;
  clear:left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```