# How to limit the amount of items per row in a flexbox without stretching them using flex-basis?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to limit the amount of items I have in a flexbox row, and the solution I see the most is using flex-basis, but that causes the elements to stretch, which I don't want, because the elements are links in the form of images, and the stretching causes the link area to be bigger than the image. Is there a way to do this? Here is my HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="spnsr-main">
   <h1 id="spnsr-title">Thank You To Our Sponsors</h1>
   <div class="spnsrs">
       <a class="spnsr-link" href="link" target="_blank"><img class="spnsr" src="../assets/sponsors/spnsr1.png"></a>
       <a class="spnsr-link" href="link" target="_blank"><img class="spnsr" src="../assets/sponsors/spnsr2.png"></a>
       <a class="spnsr-link" href="link" target="_blank"><img class="spnsr" src="../assets/sponsors/spnsr3.png"></a>
       <a class="spnsr-link" href="link" target="_blank"><img class="spnsr" src="../assets/sponsors/spnsr4.png"></a>
       <a class="spnsr-link" href="link" target="_blank"><img class="spnsr" src="../assets/sponsors/spnsr5.png"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.spnsrs {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    gap:150px 0px;
}

.spnsr {
    max-width:350px;
}

.spnsr-link {
    text-align:center;
    flex-basis:34%;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"I am trying to limit the amount of items I have in a flexbox row"* exactly? Do you want to have limited number of item on large screens? Or do you only want for the items to wrap automatically when there's limited space on smaller screens?

Comment: My goal was to force the flexbox to wrap to the next row when I had a certain number of elements in a row

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min-content` for your `max-width` to make the width of the `a`'s or the `.spnsr-link` class take the minimum width of it's content. See the snippet below:

```css
.spnsrs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.spnsr {
  max-width: 350px;
}

.spnsr-link {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="spnsr-main">
  <h1 id="spnsr-title">Thank You To Our Sponsors</h1>
  <div class="spnsrs">
    <a class="spnsr-link" href="link" target="_blank"><img class="spnsr" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5754453/pexels-photo-5754453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"></a>
    <a class="spnsr-link" href="link" target="_blank"><img class="spnsr" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5754453/pexels-photo-5754453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"></a>
    <a class="spnsr-link" href="link" target="_blank"><img class="spnsr" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5754453/pexels-photo-5754453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"></a>
    <a class="spnsr-link" href="link" target="_blank"><img class="spnsr" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5754453/pexels-photo-5754453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"></a>
    <a class="spnsr-link" href="link" target="_blank"><img class="spnsr" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5754453/pexels-photo-5754453.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

More on `min-content` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285308/how-do-min-content-and-max-content-work/64621155#64621155).